# Did Appayya Dikshitar believe in Hari-Hara abheda?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, appayya-dikshitar

Appayya Dikshitar was a sixteenth century Shaivite who believed simultaneously in Advaita Vedanta and the Saiva Siddhanta school. His works mainly praise Shiva as a result. I want to know whether he believed in the concept of Hari-Hara abheda? Does any of his works indicate Sriman Narayana as the supreme Brahman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Appayya Dikshitar apparently did believe in Hari-Hara abheda.

Quoting from pages 66-67 of "Sri Appayya Dikshitar" by Dr.N.Ramesan:

> Here is a verse of Sri Appayya Dikshitar truly instructive,
>   informative and inspiring:
>
> "viShNurvA shankaro vA shruti-shikhara-girAmastu tAtparya-bhUmiH
>   na-asmAkam tatrva vAdaH prasarati kimapi spaShTam-advaita-bhAjAm |
>   kintu-Isha-dveSha-gADhAnala-kalita-hRRidAm durmatInAm duruktIH
>   bhanktum yatno mama-ayam nahi bhavatu tato viShNu-vidveSha-shankAm ||"
>
> The meaning of the above beautiful verse is:
>
> 'I have not the slightest objection, to anyone coming to any
>   conclusion, that the spirit of the Vedas and the Vedantas, declare
>   either Vishnu or Shiva as the First God. I am a follower of the
>   Advaita doctrine. **I have no difference between Shiva and VishNu.** But
>   if in order to establish Vishnu as the main God, if somebody starts
>   abusing Shiva or hates him, I cannot bear it. There are as many proofs
>   or pramanas in the Vedas, Vedantas, Puranas and Agamas to establish
>   that Shiva is a mighty God, as there are to prove that Vishnu is a
>   powerful one. However, I am propagating my religion and indulging in
>   debate and disputation, only to persuade everyone not to hate Shiva.
>   Let no one have the slightest doubt that I either hate or wish to
>   denigrate Lord Vishnu simply because I praise the grace and greatness
>   of Lord Shiva.'
>
> The sublime devotion of Dikshita to Lord Vishnu is fully seen from his
>   great work 'Varadaraja stava' where he has sung in ecstatic poetry
>   about Lord Varadaraja of Kanchipuram. Vaishnavas declare that Vishnu
>   is the supreme being and that Shiva has a lower status, being a mere
>   jiva. Sri Dikshita however proves in his 'Ratna-traya- parIkShA' that
>   Shiva, Vishnu, Ambika, all the three are the same, viz., the supreme
>   reality, and proves it with the pramanas taken from the puranas, vedas
>   and agamas.